# I want to print single entries of one list with single entries of another list in python

Tags: python, list

For example:

There are two lists:

a= (c, d, e, f)
b= (w, x, y, z)

I want to print four lines:

- c will pick w
- d will pick x
- e will pick y
- f will pick z

I have tried a bunch of things but usually what ends up happening is that one of the lists prints in total, i.e. c will pick (w, x, y, z) d will pick (w,x,y,z) and so on.

Comment: use `zip` to iterate in parallel

Comment: Please clarify the lengths of your lists? Are they going to be same or different?

Comment: for loop with f-strings